# definite integral approximation using taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, power-series

In this question I cannot understand why they integrate to get the function that the power series represents...I also don't get how they selected the uppser and lower bound on the definite integral. Can someone explain why definite integration is used here and how they got the upper and lower limit of integration as x and 0?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They chose those bounds because

$$x^n = n \int_0^x t^{n-1} \, dt$$

This is just another way of saying that $(d/dx) x^n = n x^{n-1}$.

If you are wondering where $t$ came from, it is simply a dummy integration variable.  It has no meaning other than for integration.  To see this more clearly, let's actually solve the equation

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t) = n t^{n-1}$$

where $f(0)=0$, and we are interested in the value of $f(x)$ for some $x$.  Then we integrate both sides to get

$$f(x)-f(0) = f(x) = \int_0^x n t^{n-1} dt = n \left [ \frac{t^n}{n}\right]_0^x = x^n$$

That is, $f(x) = x^n$, which is what we want.  I hope this helps you see what the role of the dummy integration variable $t$ is.

Now, why do they integrate?  Because each term in the original power series is a derivative of $x^n$, and we known how to sum a series with terms $x^n$.  They use this to show that the original series is just the derivative of the geometric series you already know.